# create a variable with multiple product id retrived and insert through ajax in different table

Tags: php, json, ajax

Insert multiple product_id into database with ajax. After successful checkout with more than one product. How can i insert it into different table (purchase).

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "pages/ajax/insert.php",
            data: {product_id:product_id},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function(data) {
             },
            error: function(err) {
            alert(err);
            }
        });
};
```

this line of code works perfectly for one product but how can i use to send multiple product id.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the simplest is send a string parameter that is a delimited list of product IDs, you split this on the server and handle each ID as necessary. So the update might be:

```
data: {product_ids: "1,2,10,99,500"}
```

Comment: All my priduct id are retrieved from database using php. How can i use php to store id in javascript? I can echo one value  but multiple product id. And after that i have to insert those value to database. How do i split them?